# Can I define sets as an infinite process?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Can I *define* sets this way in real analysis / set theory? I mean defining sets in kind of an *infinite process* and then taking their *supremum* or *infinum*.

Let $S = \{1\}$. And for every element $x$ in S, $x/2$ is also in $S$. Since we know that all elements in S are positive ($1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, ...$), S is bounded below, so we can take the **greatest lower bound**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can define $S$ by recursion $S_0=\{1\}$, and if $S_n$ was defined, then $S_{n+1}=S_n\cup\{\frac x2\mid x\in S_n\}$. Finally, $S=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty S_n$.

This is a definition by recusion, and it is completely legitimate. But one can always define $S$ as the smallest set such that $1\in S$ and if $x\in S$ then $\frac x2\in S$. This can be proved to be the intersection of all sets satisfying this property.

And once you have a non-empty set of real numbers it's perfectly fine to take its $\inf$ or $\sup$ (which may or may not be $\pm\infty$).

Comment: For being able to take the $\inf$ in $\mathbb R$, you need that it is not empty and that it is bounded.

Comment: You are right about the non-empty, although in this context is matters only a little bit since $1\in S$ by definition... As for bounded, we can allow $\pm\infty$ as values of $\sup$ and $\inf$ and then it's fine.

Comment: This is why I specified "take the $\inf$ in $\mathbb R$". I find it somehow dangerous to consider $\infty$ as just another number, so I prefer to make different cases.

Comment: I'm not disputing that. But order-theoretic wise, allowing $\pm\infty$ is a good thing (it also makes the empty set bounded from above and below by these two points).

Answer (score 3):

Your definition is somehow incorrect, because sets are not mutable, so you cannot say $S=\{1\}$ and then modify $S$.

A cleaner way to do this (IMHO) would be the following:

> Let $S_0=\{1\}$ and, for all $n\geq 0$, $S_{n+1}=\{x\in\mathbb R:\ 2x\in S_n\}$. Then put $S=\bigcup_{n\geq 0} S_n$.

From this you can prove by induction on the sets $S_n$ that $\varnothing\subsetneq S\subset \mathbb R_+$, so you can take its lower bound.